# What is causing fatal: bad revision and how can I fix this git command?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-filter-branch

I need to completely remove a folder and all of its files from the history of a git repository and I need to ignore any future changes to that folder.

Using Git-Bash, I have already tried a filter-branch command with a git remove command nested within it. Below is my command.

`git filter-branch --force --index-filter \  "git rm -rf --cached --ignore- 
      unmatch C:\Foldername" \--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

I expected the folder to be removed from all versions of the repository, but I received an error message instead:

`fatal: bad revision 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch C:\Foldername'`

I then tried the command:
 `git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch "C:\Foldername"`
which worked by itself. However this does not accomplish the task of removing the folder from the entire history of the repository.

**Update**:
I just ran the command removing the space before "git. As shown below.

`git filter-branch --force --index-filter \ "git rm -rf --cached --ignore- 
      unmatch C:\Foldername" \--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

I now get this message:

`fatal: C:Foldername: 'C:Foldername' is outside repository
index filter failed:  git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch C:\Foldername
rm: cannot remove 'C:/.git-rewrite': Directory not empty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of weirdly placed backslashes, as if you used cut-and-paste on what was originally a multi-line command *example* like this:

```
echo I \
am a \
multi-line \
example
```

but turned it into a single line without removing the backslashes:

```
echo I \ am a \ multi-line \ example
```

Try running both—one with the newlines, so that each backslash is the *very last character* of an actual complete line, and one without—and compare the output:

```
$ echo I \
> am a \
> multi-line \
> example
I am a multi-line example
$ echo I \ am a \ multi-line \ example
I  am a  multi-line  example
```

Can you see the difference between the two outputs?  It has to do with white space, and is hard to tell sometimes.  I have a second trick I like to use, based on the fact that the `wc` command prints its arguments in error messages, one per line:

```
$ wc I \ am a \ multi-line \ example
wc: I: No such file or directory
wc: ' am': No such file or directory
wc: a: No such file or directory
wc: ' multi-line': No such file or directory
wc: ' example': No such file or directory
0 0 0 total
```

Note that the files `wc` tried to open were named `I`, `' am'`—a file name with a leading space—and so on.

In this case, `git filter-branch` thought that the `--index-filter` it should use was , which is a command that won't do much (but is actually valid here).  Then the *next* thing after that was a commit-selector, but it did not work as a commit-selector.  That's where your error came from.

In this case, since you're *not* using multiple lines, you should just remove all the backslashes.  That will give you a different problem, because `git rm -rf --cached` should be given the *relative* file names, not a full path name.

Comment: Brilliant!! Thanks for the detailed answer! It works quite well!